# Removing a process from launchd without restarting

Tags: mac-osx, launchd, launchctl, finder

I have a machine on which I do not want finder to run, so initially I made it unexecutable:

```
sudo chmod -R a-x /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

But then realised that launchd was still trying to launch finder multiple times every second, resulting in colossal log files consisiting of millions of lines of:

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[109] (com.apple.Finder[93799]) <Error>: posix_spawn("/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder", ...): Permission denied
com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[109] (com.apple.Finder[93799]) <Warning>: Exited with exit code: 1
```

So I edited `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist` so that it would not launch anymore. The problem I have now is forcing launchd to reload the plist, and therefore stop trying to launch finder. However, I cannot restart the machine.

I have tried using launchctl to both remove and unload the process but that doesn't appear to work:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist 
launchctl: Error unloading: com.apple.Finder
$ sudo launchctl remove com.apple.Finder
launchctl remove error: No such process
```

Is there anyway I can stop launchd continuously trying to load finder without restarting the machine?

Comment: Why don't you want Finder to run? Wouldn't it be better just to leave the machine at the login screen?

Comment: It is an internet kiosk, and it is much harder to exploit if Finder is not running.

Comment: Good point. You could try to run your kiosk application as if it was the Finder, maybe by making /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app a symlink to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finder is a LaunchAgent, not a LaunchDaemon, which means it's loaded as part of your login session.  Either use `launchctl unload` without `sudo`, or just log out & back in.

Comment: I can not log out and back in as I only have remote access via SSH. I have tried `launchctl unload` and `sudo -u [user] launchctl unload` where [user] is the user with Finder trying to run, but the first gets `launchctl: Error unloading: com.apple.Finder` and the second gets `Bug: launchctl.c:2325 (23930):13: (dbfd = open(g_job_overrides_db_path, O_RDONLY | O_EXLOCK | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) != -1`

Comment: Are you ssh'ing in as the same user that's running Finder?

Comment: No, that user doesn't have an SSH login for security reasons.

Comment: There's probably an easier way, but try this: get the PID of the Finder you're trying to kill, and then run `sudo launchctl bsexec [FinderPID] sudo -u [user] launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist`  If you didn't parse all that, what it does is become root (the first `sudo`), switch to the same mach bootstrap context as the Finder (`launchctl bsexec [FinderPID]`), then become the same user as the Finder (`sudo -u [user]`), then unload the agent (`launchctl unload ...`).

Comment: Finder isn't actually running though, it keeps trying to via launchd, but doesn't actually run.

Comment: Oh, that's right.  Then find another process running as part of the login session that Finder *would* be part of, and use that PID instead.

Comment: I've been able to use launchctl from ssh on jobs that are running from the console, so I don't think the mach bs context matters.

Comment: Done! I used `sudo kill -9 \`sudo launchctl list | grep peruser.502 | cut -f1\`` and that appears to work perfectly. Thanks heaps Gordon, and Neil for your help. Maybe put this as a separate answer?

Comment: Killing the user launchd process may have other ... implications.  I don't think I'd make this the recommended way of doing it.

Comment: I agree. Killing the entire launchd process is very heavy-handed. Although that worked in this particular situation, I don't think it should be put forward as THE solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your log shows that Finder is being run for user 502, but you are running `launchctl` with `sudo`, and root isn't running a Finder. Try the `launchctl unload` without `sudo`.

Comment: I have tried `launchctl unload` and `sudo -u [user] launchctl unload` where [user] is the user with Finder trying to run, but the first gets `launchctl: Error unloading: com.apple.Finder` and the second gets `Bug: launchctl.c:2325 (23930):13: (dbfd = open(g_job_overrides_db_path, O_RDONLY | O_EXLOCK | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) != -1`

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon said, you need to execute your `launchctl unload ...` command in the same mach bootstrap context of the user. launchctl itself has a facility to do this via bsexec, you just need to provide it a PID of any process running in that user context, Finder isn't running so pick a different one. The user-relative root process is `loginwindow console`, so this makes the most sense:

```
USERNAME=yourusername;export USERNAME; sudo launchctl bsexec "$(ps auxww | grep loginwindow\ console | grep "$USERNAME" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')" sudo -u "$USERNAME" launchctl unload -wF /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist
```

replace `yourusername` with the username you're affecting and voila.

Answer (score 1):

**System**
Mac OS X, version: 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)

**Task**
I wanted to prohibit, mostly the initial auto-starting but also, the automatic re-launching of the Finder (as a "simple" fix for decrypting encrypted disks) before the Finder would try (and fail) to load (and in that process discard) it's old (preferences'd) list of previous open locations..

**Reliability**
I seldom restart my computer (and haven't had any much crashes with the Finder) so 
i haven't gotten to see the effect of this configuration (that feels more like a hack) that many times.

I also see now that i haven't backed my original up so i cannot see exactly what changes i've made.

**Procedure**
Anyhow, it seems that the re-launching is removed (as expected) by setting `<key>KeepAlive</key>` in the Finder's `launchctl`(1)/`launchd`(8) property list to `<false/>`;

But, setting the `<key>RunAtLoad</key>` (again, to `<false/>`) seems to have no effect (on the *Finder* as it probably is started ~hardcoded”).

On a side-note I can say that creating a LaunchAgent - for/with any other regular application - with `<key>RunAtLoad</key>` set to `<true/>` works great if you, like I, have an app (share-service) that crashes often.

---

**References**

- file:///System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist
- The list of property list directives i was looking for i found referenced (appropriately enough) as the
   `launchd.plist`(5) `man`ual page at [Apple's technical note #2083](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html) on the subject (2011-12-28: "Last updated: 2007-11-05")

And a little **utility**
If i may recommend a graphical application for these `LaunchAgents`/`LaunchDaemons` configuring tasks i'd like to promote (without any affiliation, other than developing nationality) [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) (note the different (Snow) Leopard and Lion versions).

---

**Finally**
Sorry for the long post on this rather trivial issue.

Hope most of this is still true in version 10.7 Lion as well. Though the Finder's behaviour *could* be better (somehow, suggestivly not totaly discarding unreacahble locations) in line with "Resume" Lion feature along with "Auto Save"..

Now i just still have one other little mac thing (file sizes) to comment on at [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com)).

Answer (score 0):

The error message given in some of the comments:

```
Bug: launchctl.c:2325 (23930):13: (dbfd = open(g_job_overrides_db_path, O_RDONLY | O_EXLOCK | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) != -1
```

shows that `launchctl` is trying to open a file and failing. This could be due to permissions, but that seems unlikely, given the use of `sudo -u`. Much more likely is something related to the `O_EXLOCK` flag. Presumably `launchd` locks the database when starting a job, perhaps to check if the job is disabled, and it's retrying the job so frequently that the database file is locked most of the time.

Running a loop that continually tries to unload the job should eventually get in when `launchd` doesn't have the file locked:

```
for ((i = 0; i < 100; i++))
do
    echo -n "$i "
    launchctl unload ... && break
done
```

I know that unloading a job from `ssh` normally works, because I've done it many times, so I think the problem must be due to the frequency of the failure/reload cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're trying to do, but you're going about it entirely the wrong way.

Use the Parental Controls to set up a restricted account. Set it to use the **Simple Finder**.

Comment: I am awware of Simple Finder, but I do not wish it to run at all.